# Databricks: AWS Terraform resource to enable container service in Databricks worksapce

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I am working on POC in terraform to bring up the Databricks workspace and cluster , now i am struck in a place where i need to create a container based cluster from the workspace but i am not finding the right document to enable same from Terraform resources.

Manually i can enable the container service by following below steps

1. Go to the admin console of the workspace by clicking the Settings -> Admin Console option.
2. Click the Workspace Settings tab.
3. In the Cluster section, click the Container Services toggle.
4. Click Confirm.

Can someone please assist me on this issue ?

Comment: it's not officially available yet